# Children's book involving demon summoning and a main character who is secretly an angel

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, childrens-novel, urban-fantasy, demons

I'm trying to figure out a book series I used to read. I know the plot revolves around a group of 3 teenagers fighting a bunch of sorcerers who draw their power from summoning demons. The group is 2 guys and one girl, and the girl has a little brother. The main character's parents I think also either die or get kidnapped in the first book. The girl's little brother also gets captured as well, and at the end of the third book I think they find out the main character is some kind of angel who got sent to earth and adopted by his parents. And there's a final chapter where the boy that got kidnapped reappears holding a familiar in the form of a cat. That's about as much as I know for certain

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published?